# Markers does not appear when Infowindow with partial added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I am using Gmaps4rails gem. I could show markers without Infowindow, but after adding Infowindow in the controller, any markers do not appear. As the following, the Infowindow is rendered with partial.

What should I change the code? Thank you in advance.

clinics_controller.rb

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@clinics) do |clinic, marker|
  marker.lat clinic.latitude
  marker.lng clinic.longitude
  marker.json({:id => clinic.id})
  marker.picture ({
    "url" => "/images/red-dot.png",
    "width" => 32,
    "height" => 32
  })
  marker.infowindow render_to_string(partial: "map_infowindow", locals: {clinic: clinic})
end
```

_map_infowindow.html.erb

```
<h3><%= clinic.name %></h3>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');

  handler.buildMap({
    provider: {
      zoom: 15,
      center: {lat: 35.765, lng: 139.62}
    },
    internal: {id: 'map'}},
    function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @hash.to_json %>);
    }
  );
</script>
```

Comment: do you have console error or server error? how does the html in the 2 cases changes in the page

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have no console error or server error when Infowindow has been added. I found 2 different points in the HTML tag. Following is the missing tags when Infowindow has been added; `<canvas draggable="false" height="320" width="320" style="user-select: none; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 256px; width: 256px;"></canvas>` , and `<div class="cluster"></div>`